# Am I running PHP or suPHP

Tags: apache-2.2, php, suphp

I am testing to see if I am running `PHP` or `suPHP`. when I issue `phpinfo()`

I get back over 600 lines of data. The only mention of `suPHP` occurs here

```
<tr><td class="e">Loaded Modules </td><td class="v">core mod_log_config mod_logio prefork http_core mod_so mod_alias mod_auth_basic mod_authn_file mod_authz_default mod_authz_groupfile mod_authz_host mod_authz_user mod_autoindex mod_cgi mod_deflate mod_dir mod_env mod_mime mod_negotiation mod_php5 mod_reqtimeout mod_setenvif mod_status mod_suphp </td></tr>
```

I read on [another site](http://www.ozzu.com/unix-linux-forum/quick-way-test-suphp-t100684.html) that Server API should be `CGI` **not** `Apache` in order to be running `suPHP`

I tried posting the full output but it is over 30,000 characters. If you think it is important, I can try putting half of it.

---

**EDIT** It seems I have suPHP partially working. If I load a script and issue `getuserid()` or `get_current_user()` it returns my user information, not `www-data`. However if I try to read/write to a file that doesn't have permission for everyone to read/write, it says `failed to open stream: Permission denied`. Any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what the problem was. I had failed to disable the normal php5 module as described [here](https://lists.marsching.com/pipermail/suphp/2008-October/002048.html). All I had to do was issue the commands

```
a2dismod php5
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

If anyone else is having similar problems, here are a few sites, in addition to the [official page](http://www.suphp.org/Home.html) (which is completely useless)

[Installation instructions for beginners](http://digiground.com/linux-tips-a-tricks/195-installing-suphp-on-ubuntu-1004)

[Installation help thread on mailing list](https://lists.marsching.com/pipermail/suphp/2010-November/002390.html)

[Getting started with suPHP](http://its.virginia.edu/websupport/suphp.html)

Finally, here are the files you need to change and what changes you should apply

Add the below to your `/etc/suphp/suphp.conf` file. Note yours might be stored elsewhere, other sites suggested looking in `/etc/suphp.conf` (note also that there might be some redundancy at the end, I have not had time to fix this yet).

```
[handlers]
;Handler for php-scripts
application/x-httpd-suphp="php:/usr/bin/php-cgi"
application/x-httpd-php="php:/usr/bin/php-cgi"

;Handler for CGI-scripts
x-suphp-cgi="execute:!self"
x-httpd-suphp="php:/usr/bin/php-cgi"
```

Finally, add the following to the end of your `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file

```
suPHP_Engine on
suPHP_AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
suPHP_ConfigPath /etc/php5/cgi/
```

Answer (score 3):

That output shows you have both the DSO PHP module enabled as well as the SuPHP module, so which parser is running your scripts depends on your Apache configuration. Specifically, this is defined by the `AddHandler` directive. You can check your phpinfo() for the defined `Server API` and if it says `CGI` then based on the information you've provided, you're defaulting to SuPHP.

Comment: I have the following line in my `apache2.conf` file `suPHP_AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php`

Comment: What if it does't say `CGI` but instead `Server API` is `Apache 2.0 Handler`. What do I do then. Could you be more specific about what I have to set with `AddHandler`

Comment: Apache 2.0 Handler means you're running PHP as a DSO.

Comment: You are correct. If you look below, my mistake was in not disabling the original PHP.